# Deployment failing with HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy changes to an existing project.  This worked yesterday.  My command line is:

```
appcfg.py update .  --noauth_local_webserver --verbose
```

I get this "Bad request" error today back from app engine.  I have reauthenticated and then blew away my local copy of the project and re-downloaded it but neither have fixed this problem  What gives?

```
12:21 PM Starting deployment.
2016-04-15 12:21:10,849 INFO appcfg.py:1693 Send: /api/appversion/deploy, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'cynomix3', 'module': 'default'} 
2016-04-15 12:21:11,468 INFO appcfg.py:2559 HTTP Error (HTTP Error 400: Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400) 
12:21 PM Rolling back the update.
2016-04-15 12:21:11,469 INFO appcfg.py:1693 Send: /api/appversion/rollback, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'cynomix3', 'module': 'default'} 
Error 400: --- begin server output ---

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
--- end server output ---
```

Comment: HTTP Error 400 typically means, data stream or request sent to the server was malformed and did not follow HTTP protocol. Can u post sample of your code?..

Comment: appcfg.py is google's code

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but, did you try to deploy with another sample code, like for example the simple hello word code?

Comment: I did.  I have another test project that deploys just fine

Comment: Searching SO, came across many questions but with different solutions, so you try until one of them might fix your issue: this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387063/google-app-engine-deploy-failing-with-error-1-unauthorised) , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641566/app-engine-deployment-fails-with-client-error-400-the-request-is-invalid-for)...[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/opLO3Qpgn8g)as well...keep searching related questions until you get your fix and please post here for future reference.

Comment: I just went through all of those and a couple more I found.  No luck.  This is really frustrating.

Comment: Well ..if I were you...I would raise it to GAE support team...